# Fluid Simulation Low Quality When Dropping on Object

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, fluid-simulation, artifacts

The gold fluid when drops on the object creates meshes (or weird bumps) at point of contact. Even when I bump up the resolution to 700 the edges of the fluid are still not completely smooth. Smoothing and subdivisions are applied which help a bit but not a lot. What can produce smooth flow of liquid when it flows on the object without creating those meshes and rough edges[image]?[image]

Comment: First it would be great to not only show the settings of the domain, but all fluid objects that take part in the simulation. And the effector object on which the liquid is flowing - what are the settings of that? How did you create it, is it a high density mesh, is it using a _Subdivision Surface_ and _Displacement_ modifier etc.? And what is the order of the modifiers?

Comment: what most people don't understand: the resolution value alone says nothing about the quality of the simulation. It's like you say my plane is 2x2 miles big so my volume has to be big. Nope. It depends on the height as well. And the same is true for resolution + domain size. so pls provide blend file so we can check it out. I just can assume that you have a ridiculous big domain.

Comment: I completely understand your concern about the domain size being too big. Although i had figured that the size may be causing the issue, I'm still finding it hard to get to the core issue. What I hope to achieve is gold-like viscous fluid flowing inside the cracks of the collider object.

Comment: Now there are no modifiers applied to the effector object but the fluid seemingly reacts as if it's colliding with a low mesh object. For you to examine the settings, I'm attaching download links to the blend file and simulation cache (if you need to see the baked simulation).

Blend File: https://we.tl/t-4HlPF4NuSW
Simulation Cache: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UnCH5BIAymMm3deLQ8sedkiU6FwNHmfc?usp=sharing